# SQL Server : Show The Latest Record DATE AND TIME

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Here it is, I already use two queries but it doesn't seems to work the right way, I should view the latest PREV_BAL "5490"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7R9a.jpg)

Comment: A hyperlink isn't a question. Please actually ask a question in your question, show us what you've tried so far to solve the problem, and provide some sample data and expected results as **formatted** `text`.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551 and the accepted answer

Comment: oh.. thank.. still new here thou ehee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in you query use order by desc for both columns

```
row_number() over(partition by tenant_id order by date desc ,time_p desc) rn
```

Comment: OH... forgot the 1st query to put desc.. Thanks.. My mind is loaded of workloads .. I miss it.. Thank You :) Appreciated it

Comment: have to wait 7 min.. dont worry I will :) .. Im Still Newbie here  hehe others dont understand why I put hyperlink only which my full question are there..

Comment: @MavesNewbieHere - you shouldn't ask on a screenshot linked in the question. Please read this for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. in this case we don't need the screenshot if you put all information in your question.

Comment: thanks.. gonna put that in mind Mr.